# Receiving negative numbers from TCP connection

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Currently I have an Arduino sending 8 bytes, one by one using client.write().
This means the values range from 0-255.

My C++ application has a TCP socket connection with the Arduino and receives the bytes using the following code:

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 8

struct SensorData{
     int frontSensor;
     int backSensor;
     int leftSensor;
     int rightSensor;
  };


SensorData result{};
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

socketIdMicroprocessor = recv(clientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

if (socketIdMicroprocessor > 0) {
    result.frontSensor = (int) recvbuf[0] + (int) recvbuf[1];
    result.backSensor = (int) recvbuf[2] + (int) recvbuf[3];
    result.leftSensor = (int) recvbuf[4] + (int) recvbuf[5];
    result.rightSensor = (int) recvbuf[6] + (int) recvbuf[7];

}
```

Everything runs fine, except for the values I get when reading the results.
The results of for example frontSensor is sometimes -180.
This shouldn't be possible, because all values sent are positive and 0-255.

I would expect all values to be 0-510, could anyone explain why I'm getting negatives here?

Comment: dont send `int, float, long, ...` types over network, send `char` otherwise you can have a problem of compatibility, portability, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
```

should be:

```
unsigned char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
```

to make the cast to `int` 0-255.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result.frontSensor = (int) (unsigned char) recvbuf[0] + (int) (unsigned char) recvbuf[1]
```

The bytes received are interpreted as signed chars, ranging from -128 to 127. If you convert them to integers, you'll get values in the same -128 to 127 range, as integers cover this range too.

If you first convert to unsigned char, you'll get the expected values.

Answer (score 1):

you read in an array of *char* and you make your *int* (in fact *short*) from them

visibly in your case the *char* are signed by default, so when you receive a byte valuing 255 the *char* values -1 etc

Cast *recvbuf* to *unsigned char* before to extract the bytes

```
result.frontSensor = ((unsigned char*) recvbuf)[0] + ((unsigned char*) recvbuf)[1];
...
```

or of course use an other pointer :

```
unsigned char ubuff = (unsigned char *) recvbuf;

result.frontSensor = ubuff[0] + ubuff[1];
...
```

supposing you do not want to modify the type of *recvbuf* to *unsigned char*